# Magic methods with > 1 operands between MyClass and standard Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine I want to define a new `number` class. Say, `RationalFractions` or `GaussIntegers`, whatever. Of course, I can easily define a + b for two objects of `MyClass`. But i would like to be able to **add** an object of `MyClass` with some existing, like "integer" or "float". With the result having a relevant type (from my point of view). E.g. the result of `GaussInteger + float = GaussInteger`, `RationalFraction + integer = RationalFraction`, etc.
I guess I should somehow alter **add** for `Object` class, or "integer", "float"? Or there is a way to do it without meddling with the existing classes?

Edit. So, an example:

```
class RatFr:

    def __init__(self, m, n=1):
        self.m = m
        self.n = n

    def __add__(self, other):
        temp = (RatFr(other) if type(other) == int else other)
        return RatFr(self.m * temp.n + self.n * temp.m, self.n * temp.n)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.m}/{self.n}'


    a = RatFr(5,3)
    b = 1
    print(a)
    print(a + b)
    print(b + a)
```

I get as a result:

```
5/3
8/3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/aleksej/PycharmProjects/Alex2/playaround.py", line 19, in <module>
print(b + a)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'RatFr'
```

Trying to convert self does nothing good. As soon as the first operand is `int`, python obviously looks for integer add method.

Comment: To override addition with your object on the right side, define `__radd__()`.

Comment: Thank you! This is it. Same for __mult__ as i see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will want to override `__add__` from object, taking `self` and say `x` as parameters. You can then deal with `x` according to its type. Here you have a few options. You can do explicit type checking, but this is not very Pythonic. I would probably make a conversion function to convert from `int`, `float`, etc to your type and call it on `x`. Then you can do whatever addition would do between two objects of your type. This sort of call to a conversion function before doing an operation is done in the `mpmath` library, in the backend. Remember that you will need to check if the thing you are converting is already the right type.

Comment: Sorry, i am very new to coding. Didn't understand immediately how to put a code in a comment in a readable way. Hence used edit.

Comment: Yeah, comments are not really intended to include long code segments

Comment: @AlexBachurin You **don't** put code in comments, and you don't vandalize someone else's answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i did it by mistake, very sorry! tried to cancel but look like it is not possible to undo edit other's comment.